# need to set wordpress to root domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress installed on a live website and currently to get to it, the user needs to

type: http://mydomain.com/wp, how can change it so it will be under http://mydomain.com?

1. I know i can copy the files under the root - would that require a change in DB? where?
2. Would it be better to use a .htaccess file? if yes, can you please post a sample file?

Is there another better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the wordpress codex: [Moving Wordpress (when your domain or urls change)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change)