# Unable to Access WordPress admin after moving to root domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website launch on sub domain (`sub.domain.com`) and all working fine there. I transferred it to root address (`domain.com`) by following steps.

1. Downloaded all the file contents from sub domain directory.
2. Uploaded all those content to root directory.
3. Downloaded db script of the `sub.domain.com` install of WordPress.
4. Replaced all addresses from `sub.domain.com` to `domain.com` by notepad
5. Uploaded this script as new DB and added credentials in `wp-config.php` of root domain's WordPress.

The issue now I am facing is that it when I try to access the `/wp-admin` of new root domain’s WordPress it doesnot accept them.

I created a admin user [directly into db from this site](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/), but it also is not working.

Comment: See if this extremely similar question helps you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710939/need-to-set-wordpress-to-root-domain

Comment: I used notepad for replacing all values, I am uanble to guess from this link where it went all wrong , Can you have alternate solution ? Can I access the sub domain directory web from root address ? that also I acheived via htaccess but in that I have to access the wp-admin by same sub-domain address

Comment: A lot of values in the WordPress database are PHP serialized values.  The serialization includes the length of the string, so if you change a string to one with a different length without updating the length value, you'll break the serialization.  You're better off copying the database without changing anything, then updating the values using the "Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script" mentioned in the link in the answer @Nextraztus referenced.

Comment: I have used the serialization tool , everything is set , only issue is that the previous user names are not working

Comment: I created a admin user directly into db from http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/   , but it also not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you move a WordPress site, you need to properly adjust configurations in your WordPress install in the `wp-config.php` file on the following variables:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://domain.com/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://domain.com/');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/your/wordpress/wp-content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://domain.com/wp-content');
```

This will force your install to use the `domain.com` URLs.  Also, when you do this the first time set the `RELOCATE` setting to `true` like this:

```
define('RELOCATE', true);
```

That basically tells WordPress to rejigger (that’s my technical term for it) it’s stored settings for the new settings. And after you have reloaded your site & it works as expected, set `RELOCATE` setting back to `false` like this:

```
define('RELOCATE', false);
```